# Is it possible to filter out closed questions from the interesting list?

Tags: support, questions, tag-watching, interesting-page

Is it possible to keep closed questions out of my interesting questions list?

Comment: Even closed questions can be "interesting"!

Comment: @TheEstablishment they can be interesting but there should be an option to indicate that a closed question is never interesting for you.

Comment: Well, behind the snark of my comment, there was an actual point. Closed questions are not *permanently* closed. In fact, closed questions often get re-opened. So closed questions can still be interesting if you happen across them, because you can edit them to comply with our question guidelines and then vote to re-open them (or flag them for moderator attention). And if they would otherwise be "interesting" to you, it's more likely that you're a good person to edit and improve them. This is why there's no option to hide all closed questions. That option is labeled "delete".

Comment: So from your comments I make the assumption there is no way to filter them out?

Comment: I don't think so, but if I knew that for sure, I would have posted an answer. I used a comment instead because I'm not actually answering your question.