# Grey/fade out closed questions (like questions with ignored tags)

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, markdown

Could the closed questions be grayed out like questions with ignored tags, so that when you open up the default page of SO or a SE site, they attract less attention?

Related but not identical:

[Would like to be able to ignore all closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45643/would-like-to-be-able-to-ignore-all-closed-questions)

[Is it possible to filter out closed questions from the interesting list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132915/is-it-possible-to-filter-out-closed-questions-from-the-interesting-list)

[Please add the ability to filter [Closed] questions out of my results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/please-add-the-ability-to-filter-closed-questions-out-of-my-results)

Answer (score 9):

When a question is closed, it is with the hope that it can be improved and re-opened.  Hiding closed questions would subvert this purpose.

For this reason, I disagree with the proposal to grey-out or otherwise hide closed posts.

Answer (score 3):

Just because a question is Closed doesn't mean it's "dead".

Questions are closed because they're not *currently* a good question for the site they're on. They are still editable and, in many cases they can and should be edited to be better, on-topic questions.

If they can't be fixed, of course, most of the time they should be deleted. Deleted questions are already hidden from view (and is a mostly permanent state).

So I'm not in favor of fading closed questions like ignored tags. Instead, "Closed" should be a klaxon to the world: **Save me!**

Answer (score 2):

The separation of closed posts is done from title itself.

With colour anything (Gray), it will attract more closed questions than normal.

And with the fade out, it will fade out from view list. But this will also decrease the possibility of reopening good questions that have been closed. Some closed question are also good or have been improved after closure.

Comment: That is why I suggested fading them out and not completely removing them.